# Is this question off-topic, and if so, how can I report it?

Tags: discussion, rules

I recently saw a question on SO that appears to be an Application feature question rather than a programming question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052142

Isn't that a rule violation?  I looked for a way to report; but, could not find one.  Did the posting rules change?  I have not been active on SO for several months dues to other commitments.

Answer (score 5):

To get this out of the way, since your reputation is where it's at, you're looking to **flag** the post.  *What* you flag it as we'll describe here.

First of all, this is how the question leads off:

> I have an application that allows me to take a feed from either the front or back camera on an Android Smartphone and stream this video to a remote user.
>
> Rather than streaming the front or back I want to stream the video from a USB camera. The issue is that I do not have access to the source code or the developers.

So, we're already talking about another application which the OP hasn't authored, and doesn't have direct control over.  No API?  No code?  I see a problem with this since it really is some generic camera application for Android which may or may not allow this level of configuration.

What do we do?  We have a few options, although one fits better than the others.

- **Flag/Close it for being about general software/hardware.**

  Okay, this works, since it is about general software and hardware related to Android, but the cardinality of the closure is dissatisfying. Perhaps if the OP had provided more information about what app this *was* and what version of Android they needed it to work on, we could've pointed them to [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).
- **Flag/Close it for being too broad.**

  Yes, it's *very* broad, but the worst part about this close reason is that it implies, by some miracle of editing, that the OP could make this question somehow *better*.  In actuality, I don't see what edits could be made to improve it to fit on Stack Overflow; the only real scope narrowing that can/should be done is specifying the program and the versions of Android.  That *still* wouldn't make it on-topic since it's not asking about any code they're in control of; they're just using an app on their device.

One last thing to consider; the OP in this question hasn't been around since **13 June 2016**.  They asked that question on **5 May 2016**.  It's (as I post this) **30 November 2016**.  This means that in ***seven months***, the OP didn't find it pertinent enough to maintain their question or provide any clarifications or scope narrowing efforts, so the best thing to do *now* is to delete it.

Once you reach that rep level and you see questions with a similar lack of interest from the OP and no real chance of salvation without them, it's not the worst thing in the world to cast a delete vote.

Answer (score -1):

The question is too broad for SO.

> *"is there anyway I can effectively swap out the video from either the front or back camera for the feed from the USB camera?"*

Can be considered a request for a library / off-site resource, and it's "too broad". There's no indication of any attempts from the OP.

As such, this question can be closed as "Too broad".

Comment: There is nothing in the question indicating the OP is asking for an off-site resource or library. Why do you think he does? Also you don't really answer the question asked.

Comment: A library that handles USB cameras? Documentation on how to define which camera's the device can recognize? In the end, what matters is that this question gets closed.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I don't know this particular subject, but in my opinion, it is also important *how* the question is closed, because the closure blurb communicates back to the OP what course of action they should take in order to get the question reopened and answered.

Comment: @NisseEngström: Sure, but that doesn't mean _"It's too broad"_ is an invalid answer to this meta question, which is what Patrick was saying before I posted this answer. It's the whole reason I posted this answer. Then, arguing about semantics while the mainsite question can (arguably) be closed for _any_ of the mentioned reasons is pretty darn pointless. In the end, the question isn't "okay".

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'm not saying that *"too broad"* is wrong. I just wanted to add to the  *"what matters is that this question gets closed"* statement that there is more to it than that. Perhaps not in this case, since the OP hasn't been around since June.